# JTable: Filling fields with data in custom cell editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've created my custom cell editor for changing the adress in my table model. But when it opens for the first time, my text fields are empty. When I enter the text and I save it, next time I click on that cell, editor gets the data from table.

Editor contains 2 text fields and one combobox.

My question is: **How to pass the data from table to editor first time it opens? Thanks!**

Comment: An actually [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses.  Initially, `getTableCellEditorComponent` is called, passing the `value` of the cell via the `value` parameter...

Comment: @The_CoA: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).